# Dependents events with i.i.d R.Vs

Tags: probability

I have this problem:

given:
$$
(w_1 ,w_2 ,w_3 , w_4, w_5)\sim N(0,1)\:, i.i.d
$$
I want to find the probability :

$$
w_1,w_2
$$
are smaller than 
$$w_4+\mu,w_4+\mu,w_5+\mu ; \:\mu \:is \:some \:positive \:constant \\ 
P(w_1<\mu+w_3\cap w_1<\mu+w_4\cap w_1<\mu+w_5\cap w_2<\mu+w_3\cap w_2<\mu+w_4\cap w_2<\mu+w_5)
$$
i know i can't just break up the intersections, but i don't know how to explain the dependency of the events, although the R.V are i.i.d ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find $P(X-\mu<Y)$ with $X=\max(w_1,w_2)$ and $Y=\min(w_3,w_4,w_5)$. Note that 
$$
P(Y>y)=(1-\Phi(y))^3,\quad y\in\mathbb{R},
$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution, and hence by independence of $X$ and $Y$ we have
$$
P(X-\mu<Y)={\rm E}[[1-\Phi(X-\mu)]^3]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} 2[1-\Phi(x-\mu)]^3\Phi(x)\varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
where we have used that $X$ has density $x\mapsto 2\Phi(x)\varphi(x)$.

Comment: thx Stefan in fact that is my answer to this problem. but i'm trying to explain to my supervisor my i can't just break up the intersections into multiplication, although the R.V are i.i.d, why are the events are dependent?

Comment: Why should $\{X<Y\}$ and $\{Z<Y\}$ be independent just because $X,Y,Z$ are independent?

Comment: got your point ,but i don't see why $$P(X<Y\cap Z<Y) \ne P(X<Y)P(Z<Y)$$ ?

Comment: I don't see why you would expect there to be equality.

Comment: O.k now i can see it. thank you very much.